# aggregations merged in hits in elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Just for an example, let's say I have a database, or an elastic index, holding sales persons and also all their customer visits past and into the future.

Lets also say I want to produce a list of these sales persons and show how many customer visits they have scheduled.
In SQL I would do something like this:

(mind: SQL is probably not all that correct, because it is just written here and just for telling what I am intending to do)

```
select foo, bar, sum(baz) from table_barbaz 
where appointment_date > now()
group by bar
```

is it possible to get the same result in Elastic search? Like a list of documents sort of looking like this:

```
{
    "foo": "Salesmen John", 
    "bar": "Client visit this week",
    "sum_baz": 99
}
```

Not sure if this is related to nested aggregations or something else.

Below is a mapping that could have been used in this example. As the real mapping is internal IP, I don't really want to share it publicly.

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "salesman_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "salesman_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "customer_visit": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "customer_visit_start_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||strict_date"

        },
        "customer_visit_end_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||strict_date"

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's definitely possible. Can you show your index mapping?

Comment: @Val - I have added a mapping

Comment: Ok, I guess `foo = salesman_name` and `baz = customer_visit ` but can you tell which concrete field would be `bar`?

Comment: I thought I had posted this. But I cannot see it. Lets - for this case - say it is customer_visit_start_date. It is a real use case, but the data and structure i have is IP, so I cannot post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, an aggregation query like the following one would give you the number of customer visits for each salesman, for each day:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "salesmen": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "salesman_name",
        "size": 20
      },
      "aggs": {
        "days": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "customer_visit_start_date",
            "interval": "day"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "visits": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "customer_visit"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked according to the information I gave. So I have given it the correct answer check + point. Question as a follow up. Let's say you want to show both the salesman_id and salesman_name ?

Comment: There's a 1:1 match between salesman_id and salesman_name, right? in that case, you can nest another terms sub-aggregation for salesman_id below salesman_name